# Ubuntu 12.04 , Download Flash videos from nowvideo website?

Tags: 12.04, video, flash

first of all i'm apology to ask this repeated Question.

Actually i'm new to Ubuntu, previously i'm using Windows in that using `Internet Download Manager` i'm download all the videos file and one more feature is when we are watch any video it should be enable and ask `Download this video`.

Particularly asking this Question, now a days Most of the site videos running on flash player (.flv formate) so hear their is no way for getting site video id when we are copy the running video url then html file only downloded.

So please help me download videos from `nowvideo` like website videos.

Is their any software like `Internet Download Manager` to ask running video Download Option?

Comment: AFAIK, no. But maybe you can use a firefox extension called netvideohunter, which can download most of the online videos(although not as powerful as IDM).

Answer (score 3):

You can download videos from nowvideo with no addictional software

1. Go to the novideo url with Google Chrome
2. Open the *Developer Tools* CTRL + SHIFT + J
3. From inside the *Developer Tools* open the *Network* panel
4. Start the video from the browser window
5. now in the Network panel you can see the video connection (the longest bar)
   [image]
6. right click on it and select "Copy link address"
7. open a terminal and type **wget** and SHIFT + INS, so that the command would be somenting like

   wget http://s122.nowvideo.ch/dl/blabla/bla/blabla.flv?client=FLASH

Comment: my reputation doesn't allow me to post this image to better explain point 5 http://i.stack.imgur.com/izJiw.png

Comment: I added your image after step 5 :).

Answer (score 0):

You could install a flash downloader add-on to Firefox. I like [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/), but if you browse Mozilla's [add-on website](http://addons.mozilla.org/), you'll fine plenty of others to pick from.